# FragmentActivity, CursorLoader and getActivity undefined

Tags: android-fragmentactivity, android-cursorloader

I'm using a `CursorLoader` in a `FragmentActivity` following the sample code [here](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html).

When I try to compile, however, Eclispe gives me the error:

```
The method getActivity is undefined for the class
```

How I can solve this?

Comment: post some code , getActivity() is defined in fragments, where are you trying to call it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FragmentActivity` does not have any `getActivity()` method like `Fragment` have. If you want to get the activity you should use `this` keyword inside `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Why in the example they use FragmentActivity without the this?